# Java Object Constructor with VarArgs

Tags: java, object

So I have a function in my Program class:

```
public class Program {
    IntegSet i1, i2, i3, i4;
    i1 = new IntegSet();
    i2 = new IntegSet(1,2,5);
    i3 = new IntegSet();
    i4 = new IntegSet(i2);
}
```

And I have a constructor in my IntegSet class:

```
public class IntegSet{
    private final int MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE=2000;
    private boolean [] data = new boolean[MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE+1];

    public IntegSet(int... elts) {

    }
```

My program is about making integer sets. I know that in my Program class I am creating objects, and constructing them in my Set function in my Set class. But I don't know how to code the constructor. I can only have those member variables. Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I have this first function, and I think it's ok.

```
public IntegSet(int... elts) {
   for(int iteration = 0; iteration < elts.length; iteration++) {
       data[iteration] = true;
    }
}
```

But what about this function

```
public IntSet(IntSet source){
    this.data = source.data;
}
```

Is this a copy constructor? I'm a little confused on how that works. And how it differs from this function:

```
public void setTo(IntSet source){}
```

where I am supposed to call it with this:

```
i3.setTo(i3.subtract(i1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few comments to be made here.  First, if you want the variables at the class-level in your `Set` class, you should prepend them with `static`.  These will be the same for any instance of the `Program` class.  You will also need to initialize these static variables in the `main` function or in the same line as they're declared.

```
public class Test {
   static MySet i1, i2, i3, i4;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      i1 = new MySet();
      i2 = new MySet(1,2,5);
      i3 = new MySet();
      i4 = new MySet(i2);
   }
}
```

Regarding your `Set` class, I would first recommend not naming it `Set`, since it will conflict with `java.util.Set`.  Try something like `MySet` as seen below.

```
public class MySet {
   private final int MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE = 2000;
   private boolean[] data;

   public MySet(int... elts) {
      data = new boolean[MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE + 1];

      for (int eltNdx = 0; eltNdx < elts.length; eltNdx++) {
         if (elts[eltNdx] <= MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE) { //Prevent ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            data[elts[eltNdx] + 1] = true;
         } else {
            //Above the maximum size. Either don't store or handle accordingly.
         }
      }
   }

   public MySet(MySet anotherSet) {
      System.arraycopy(anotherSet.data, 0, this.data, 0, MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE);
   }
}
```

#### Responding to your EDIT:

I adjusted the assignment in the constructor to `data[elts[eltNdx] + 1]` above to leave a spot for value `0` via the `+ 1`.  I was also incorrectly using the eltNdx to index the data array instead of the value (fixed now and tested).

The constructor you included will work, except you should verify the values in `elts` don't exceed the maximum allowed value as you insert save them in the set.  This is what I'm doing in my solution with `if (elts[eltNdx] <= MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE)`.

For the constructor accepting another `IntSet`, the initially posted code made the two objects share the data array.  This isn't how `java.util.Set`s work, so I adjusted that constructor to copy the values of the data array of `anotherSet` into the data array of the object being constructed.

Here's an example of how `java.util.Set`s work:

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
set1.add(10);
set1.add(11);
Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>(set1);

System.out.println("Initial set 1:\n" + set1);
System.out.println("set2 constructed with set1:\n" + set2);
set1.add(12);
System.out.println("Adjusted set1 with 12:\n" + set1);
System.out.println("set2 after set1 adjustment:\n" + set2);
```

Output:

```
Initial set 1:
[10, 11]
set2 constructed with set1:
[10, 11]
Adjusted set1 with 12:
[10, 11, 12]
set2 after set1 adjustment:
[10, 11]
```

Notice how adding 12 to `set1` does not affect `set2` after `set2` is constructed.  This is because they are internally represented by **separate data-structures**.

With the adjusted (current) code, we can observe the same behavior.  (I added a getData() method which just returns the data array, since it's private)

```
i1 = new IntegSet(0, 2);
i2 = new IntegSet(i1);

System.out.println("i1: " + Arrays.toString(i1.getData()));
System.out.println("i2: " + Arrays.toString(i2.getData()));
i1.getData()[2] = false;
System.out.println("i1: " + Arrays.toString(i1.getData()));
System.out.println("i2: " + Arrays.toString(i2.getData()));
```

Output:

```
i1: [true, false, true, false]
i2: [true, false, true, false]
i1: [true, false, false, false]
i2: [true, false, true, false]
```

Setting `i1`'s value at position `2` to `false` does not affect `i2`.  Note this is how you could modify your set after construction.

I'm assuming the `setTo(IntSet source)` function you mentioned should use [System.arrayCopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) exactly as the constructor (re-constructing the data array).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry about my objects not being in main, I forgot to copy that over. Good idea on the name change of the class. Unfortunately, I have to create a program where I use those 2 member variables. I can't change the data array to of type int. Is there another way around this?

Comment: I wasn't sure about the MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE, since your data array stores booleans.  I can help with it once your question is more clear.  What exactly are you trying to store in this class?  It's not possible to store the integer values with a boolean array.

Comment: Hmm ok. Sorry about the confusion haha. So I'm creating a program where I am creating objects that represent integer sets. The sets can contain numbers between and including both 0 and 2000. So the maximum size one set could be is 2001, that is if every within that range is being used. Could it be that it depends on the value of the integer passed to the function, and it's relationship with the index of the boolean array?

Comment: The maximum number of elements is 2001. The maximum size of an element is 2000. I'm thinking along the lines of this: I need to add the integer _n_ to my set. I set the data array index _n_ to true. Is this a valid way?

Comment: Sorry, I finally realized what you mean.  Also I had some trouble with the editing haha.  Let me know if the edited code looks accurate now!

Comment: Hi @Matt I edited my question, if you could take a look at it that would be awesome :)

Comment: Hey again @Matt I posted a new question

Comment: Beyond your initial edit?  I have responded to it and don't see anything else.

Comment: Thanks I've adjusted the constructors. Note that I am not actually using the java.util.Set. I am just using objects with my boolean array that represent an integer set. The setTo(IntegerSet) function should set the target set to have the same contents as the parameter set. The subract function should make a new set that is equal to the first set, except that any element from the second set is removed. But why would I need the setTo function if I have the copy constructor. Is it beacuse I'm calling it a different way by doing this: `i3.setTo(i3.subtract(i1))` vs. this `i4 = new MySet(i2);`

Comment: I understand you're not using `java.util.Set`, but I can tell your assignment is trying to model its behavior (plus it's valuable to understand).  The setTo allows you to change an existing object's data without constructing a new object like the copy constructor.  You could still do `i4 = new MySet(i3.subtract(i1))` in your example.  I'll let you write the subtract `function` on your own :)